# What is the most energy effecient type of RF oscillator?

Tags: rf, oscillator

Here are the options: the Gunn Diode, the Barkhausen-Kurz Tube(AKA "transmitting triode"), the so-called Lighthouse Tube, the cavity Magnetron, the reflex Klystron. I'm leaving out the Gyrotron because it is very much a cut above all the rest but can someone rank them from least to most in terms of energy efficiency.

Comment: What did your research show you? Add the information into your question.

Comment: None of the above.

Comment: Probably the Poulsen arc.

Comment: Gyrotron without energy recovery of residual electron beam energy continuous / pulsed operation = 30-40% / 40-50%  & with energy recovery <50% /  < 70%.  From [here](https://www.google.co.nz/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%252Fs11141-006-0112-3%2Flookinside%2F000.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Farticle%2F10.1007%252Fs11141-006-0112-3&docid=hR95LNh07wDKRM&tbnid=xRHqEFNzbosT-M%3A&w=738&h=955&ved=0ahUKEwjRlsaMtN7NAhUJyGMKHY-CABAQMwgoKAwwDA&iact=mrc&uact=8&biw=1536&bih=826).

Comment: ... 
**IF** correct and Bruce's cavity magnetron figures are correct the two are comparable.

Comment: Anda aka: Then WHAT is?

Answer (score 2):

Gunn diode 5%, Barkhausen-Kurz Tube 13%, reflex Klystron 28%, 'Lighthouse' tube (planar triode) 30-60%, cavity Magnetron 65%.

Comment: Out of curiosity can I have a citation please if you've got one? I recently read an anecdote that at very high power(~100kW) and at certain frequencies(in the low GHz range), magnetrons can achieve up to 90% efficiency but don't quote me on it!